# active nav link not changing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, navigation

THis is not working, went trough the internet tried another methods in css but the color of the active item on the page when i scroll is always white i want it colored for example yellow

CSS

```
   <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="200" id="page-top">
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark shadow fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Us
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a id="sss" class="nav-link" href="#team">The Team</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#impressions">Impressions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #b6a50c;
}
```

Comment: Your css is assuming that you use javascript to add the "active" class do you?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap adds the `.active` class to the **link**  (`a`), not to its parent, i.e. the **list item** (`li`), which is what your selectors would apply to.

Therefore your selector should look like this:

```
.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav > li > a.active {
  color: #b6a50c;
}
```